# Unit test is failing when ContinueWith is used with System.Threading.Tasks.Task

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, task-parallel-library, moq

I am trying to add unit-tests for my code where I am using `Task` from TPL to update values into a database. For unit-test, I am using `NUnit` and `Moq`. Here are some code snippets from my project.

```
*//service*
public interface IServiceFacade{
   Task SynchronizeDataset (string datasetName);
}

*//The method call I want to test*
_ServiceFacade.SynchronizeDataset(DATASET_NAME);

*//In my test, I want to verify if this method is called*
mock_IServicesFacade.Setup(sf => sf.SynchronizeDataset(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(It.IsAny<Task>());
presenter.InitializeView();
mock_IServicesFacade.Verify(sf => sf.SynchronizeDataset(NSUserUtilStrings.DATASET_ACHIEVEMENT), Times.Once());
```

This is working. But when I add `ContinueWith` with the service method call like this...

```
_ServiceFacade.SynchronizeDataset(DATASET_NAME).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    if (t.IsFaulted)
    {
        //do something
    }
});
```

this test code is not working.Test is failed and it shows this error...

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object

Stacktrace:

> atPresenters.UnitTests.DeviceCategoryPresenterTest.InitializeView_Called
>   () [0x00241] in DeviceCategoryPresenterTest.cs:56 
>         at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
>         at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
>   binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture) [0x00038] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305

and I am not sure how can I fix it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "this test code is not working" - what does it mean? Throws exception? Doesn't give expected results? Then what results are expected?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question with error log, stacktrace.

Comment: What DB context are you using/injecting for testing? If there is nothing then a null task is expected?

Comment: I setup it to return any Task, so It can be null. But that is not failing the test if I do not use ContinueWith, because I only verify if this method is called with the parameter one time. But it is failing if I add ContinueWith.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact here is that you are skipping your continuation by passing the valid task instead of `It.IsAny<Task>`. The one example is to do something like this

**.NET < v4.6**

```
mock_IServicesFacade
    .Setup(sf => sf.SynchronizeDataset(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(true)))
```

**.NET >= v4.6**

```
mock_IServicesFacade
    .Setup(sf => sf.SynchronizeDataset(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask))
```

You can even try to make your continuation with option `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` because you are only interested in `IsFaulted` scenario.

Be aware that you are not testing continuation part only skipping it. If you really want to test\verify continuation part be careful with it. It seems that your logic is service side logic so there `TaskScheduler` will use default `SynchronizationContext` and schedule continuation on the `ThreadPool` thread. Of course this is executed within unit test runner context which is the same. Basically your tests could finish even before continuation task is executed.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know that I am not testing the continuation part. But for this method, I just want to verify it is called with given parameter. Your given solution is working. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In your setup you set up the function to return `null`. You already stated this in a comment, `It.IsAny<Task>()` returns `null`.

```
Setup(sf => sf.SynchronizeDataset(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(It.IsAny<Task>());
```

So if we break this down:

```
_ServiceFacade.SynchronizeDataset(DATASET_NAME).ContinueWith(t =>
           {
               if (t.IsFaulted)
               {
                  //do something
               }
           });
```

... equals

```
// This works, but returns null, so testing anything from this point is limited.
var myNullTask = _ServiceFacade.SynchronizeDataset(DATASET_NAME);

myNullTask.ContinueWith(t => ... ); // This yields NullReferenceException
((Task)null).ContinueWith(t => ... ); // Equivalent to line above
```

Seems like you are writing an integration test which does not apply to your code (if your actual code does assume non-null as return). If this is the case,  I suggest changing your setup to something like:

```
Setup(sf => sf.SynchronizeDataset(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);
```

Comment: I got the point. It.IsAny<Task>() returns null and cannot call ContinueWith for a null object. Right? I am trying to follow your suggestion. But it shows, Task does not contain a definition for CompletedTask.

Comment: Ok. I got the answer from Lepijohnny's answer. But I upvoted your answer too. Thank you.